# how to select fields from Firestore where fields values are not the same

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firestore how do we select documents that do not have the same field values as another document has.

Example: all documents have the same fields but for that field some of the values are the same. doc1 "description"= yes, doc2 "description"= working, doc3 "description" = working

I would like for my output to be:
"yes" and "Working"

Currently I get:
yes, working, working

```
templateRef
      .where('owner', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      //.where('description', '!==', 'description')
      //.limit(1)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const data = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const d = {
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          };
          data.push(d);
        });

        return data;
      })
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information about your data structure of the documents to make the question more understandable?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain with some diagrams and examples? With `.where('description', '!==', 'description').limit(1)` you'll select one doc for which the `description` field exists and its value is different than `description`.

Comment: To understand better, you want to get all documents in which the description field holds the value either of "yes" or "working", right?

Comment: I included a photo to better explain. I hope this helps to understand what needed

Comment: Can you explain your broader goal, as there may be other approaches than just querying, e.g. with denormalization. In other words, why do you want to select only one? Do you always want to select only on doc that has description = working?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to compare two documents in one Firestore query, as the value for a query always has to be specified as a literal. So your only option is to first load the one document, take the value from it, and then pass that value to the second query.